# Issue using custom insert media for plugin - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this sample code I am using to insert media as attachments for custom made orders.  I downloaded a Role Plugin which allowed me to be able to see Media but I don't want to see media of another user so I had a question about how to show only media I uploaded or this user uploaded.  But back to the main question.  This is the code I am using to open the `media upload` window once a button is clicked:

```
var file_frame;
var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id; // Store the old id
var set_to_post_id = 10; // Set this

  $('.upload_image_button').on('click', function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if ( file_frame ) {
      // Set the post ID to what we want
      file_frame.uploader.uploader.param( 'post_id', set_to_post_id );
      // Open frame
      file_frame.open();
      return;
    } else {
      // Set the wp.media post id so the uploader grabs the ID we want when initialised
      wp.media.model.settings.post.id = set_to_post_id;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_title' ),
      button: {
        text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' ),
      },
      multiple: true  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    });

    file_frame.on( 'select', function() {

        var selection = file_frame.state().get('selection');

        selection.map( function( attachment ) {

          attachment = attachment.toJSON();

          // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
        });
     });

    // Finally, open the modal
    file_frame.open();
  });

  // Restore the main ID when the add media button is pressed
  jQuery('a.add_media').on('click', function() {
    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
  });
```

Now the issue here is, once I upload an image.  I just get an error returned which states `An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.`  That is it.  I am not sure why I would be getting this error?

Source code I got was from `http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/`

Suggestions, thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something in php....mess with this i cant remember the filenames offhand...

```
function filter_media_files( $wp_query_obj ) {

     global $pagenow;
     global $current_user;

    if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') ) // users not admins
       return;

    if( 'upload.php' == $pagenow && 'media-upload.php' == $pagenow) {
       $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->id );
    } else {
       return;
    }

return;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_media_files');
```